# Setting up authentication session information using AngularJS and PassportJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, passport.js

I am trying to set up a content management system using [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) on the client side, and [ExpressJS](http://expressjs.com/) on the server side with [PassportJS](http://passportjs.org/) for authentication.

Currently I have two service methods on the client side: one for logging in, and another which requires authentication to access (Irrelevant parts omitted):

### client.js (Client side)

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope, authenticator, gameService){
    authenticator.signIn({username: 'admin', password: 'lynda'})
    .success(function(data){
        $rootScope.session = data; //not sure if this is needed
        console.log(data);
    });
    $scope.post = function(){
        gameService.createNewGame({"name": "Brand new game",
                   "description": "new",
                   "image": "image.png"})
        .success(function(data){
        console.log(data);
        });
    };
});

app.factory('authenticator', function($http, $cookies){
    var signIn = function(userData){
      if(userData){
        return $http.post("/authenticate", userData);
      }
    };

    return {
        signIn: signIn,
    };
});

app.factory('gameService', function($http){
    return {
    createNewGame: function(newGame){
        return $http.post('/games', {data: newGame});
    }
});
```

On the server side, I have attempted to set up passport authentication following the [guides](http://passportjs.org/guide/) on passportJS site. (For the moment,authentication credentials are hard coded) :

### app.js (Server side)

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

var db = require('mongoskin').db('mongodb://administrator:thePassword@localhost:27017/website');

//allow parsing of body messages
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // application/json
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true})); // application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(session({secret: 'Super top secret',
         resave: true,
         saveUninitialized: true}
           ));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done){
    done(null, user.username);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(name, done){
    done(null, {username: name});
});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function(username, password, done){
    if(username === 'admin' && password === 'lynda'){
        return done(null, {username: 'admin'});
    }

    return done(null, false);
    }
));

function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.isAuthenticated());
    next();
}

app.post('/authenticate', passport.authenticate('local'),
     function(req,res){
         res.send("Authenticated successfully");
     });

app.post('/games', isLoggedIn,
     function(req,res){
         console.log("You made it into the post");
         db.collection('games').insert({
         "name": req.body.name,
         "description": req.body.description,
         "image": req.body.image
         },function(err,result){
         if(err) throw err;
         res.send(result);
         });
     });

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    res.status(404).send("Sorry, can't find that!");
});

var server = app.listen(80, function(){
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;

    console.log("App listening at http://%s:%s", host, port);
});
```

When I start up the server and run the client code. I get the response from the authenticate endpoint saying that I have "Authenticated Successfully". However,  when I then click a button on my page to make the post request to '/games/', the server code runs the "isLoggedIn" function and reports that req.isAuthenticated() is false.

What is it I am missing? I feel like I don't quite understand from reading the docs how sessions are supposed to work with angular, and that perhaps I am missing some crucial setup step.

Comment: I check code for server side js and it works, so probably problem is in angular code. You can try to make an http interceptor from this guide: https://vickev.com/#!/article/authentication-in-single-page-applications-node-js-passportjs-angularjs

Comment: @vanadium23 Thanks for the link, I will check it out. However, I am more interested in my main problem of simply getting my server to setup up a valid session and verify that it is authenticated. Once I understand and have a session working properly, *then* I will attempt to implement redirects, interceptors etc.

You mentioned there might be a problem with the client side angular code? Any ideas what might be missing / going wrong?

Comment: @CraigInnes Did you ever get around your issue? If so - please post your answer here, would be curious to see how you resolved it.